# Ambiguous reference to member 'contains'

Tags: swift, struct, collections, swift4

I have defined a struct for the Stack:

```
struct Stack<T> {
    private(set) var elements = [T]()
    var isEmpty: Bool { return elements.isEmpty }

    mutating func push(newElement: T) {
        elements.append(newElement)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> T {
        return elements.removeLast()
    }

    func top() -> T? {
        return elements.last
    }
}
```

When I use the method to get the last element and check if it is in the collection:

```
if operators.contains(stack.top()!) {
//do smth
}
```

compiler raises an error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'contains'"

Update: The collection is defined as:

```
struct Operator: OperatorType {
    let name: String
    let precedence: Int
    let associativity: Associativity
    // same operator names are not allowed
    var hashValue: Int { return "\(name)".hashValue }

    init(_ name: String, _ precedence: Int, _ associativity: Associativity) {
        self.name = name; self.precedence = precedence; self.associativity = associativity
    }
}
```

And init with:

```
let operators: Set <Operator> = [
    Operator("%", 4, .Right),
    Operator("*", 3, .Left),
    Operator("/", 3, .Left),
    Operator("+", 2, .Left),
    Operator("-", 2, .Left)
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is that `if` statement? What is `someCollection`?

Comment: Most likely `someCollection` does not contain the same type of element as `stack`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `contains` method you are looking for only exists where `Array.Element : Equatable`

> Taken from the [stdlib](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d9f7d1414e07a82e5e111438a34faaf343a83829/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L510).
>
> ```
> extension Array where Element : Equatable {
>
>      ...
>
>      public func contains(_ element: Element) -> Bool
> }
> ```

Assuming `someCollection` is `Array<Stack>` then you would need to change `Stack` to:

```
struct Stack<T: Equatable> : Equatable {
```

And with `Swift 4.1` the `Equatable` conformance is handled automatically. [Source](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md)